# Recursive algorithm Merge sort

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I'm confused with the order of execution of this code, when python interpreter moves to `m_short(a)` what will happen? the code after those 2 recursive function only executed after its divides the array of 2?

```
def m_sort(arr):
  if len(arr) > 1:
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    a = arr[mid:]
    b = arr[:mid]

    m_sort(a)
    m_sort(b)

    i = j = k = 0

    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
      if a[i] < b[j]:
        arr[k] = a[i]
        i += 1

      else:
        arr[k] = b[j]
        j += 1

      k += 1

    # Missing Elements
    while i < len(a):
      arr[k] = a[i]
      i += 1
      k += 1

    while j < len(b):
      arr[k] = b[j]
      j += 1
      k += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try adding some prints or stepping through with pdb and you can probably answer your own question.

Comment: Hint - What is the requirement for m_sort to return instead of calling itself twice? When is the first time m_sort will return?